# Q-Q line in log-log space (log="xy"): abline's argument 'untf' does not work as expected

Tags: r

I try to understand why `qqline` does not give me what I expect if (and only if) `log="xy"`:

```
th <- 0.5
n <- 1e3
set.seed(271)
x <- rgamma(n, shape=th)
qF <- function(p) qgamma(p, shape=th)

## 1) Q-Q plot in normal space
plot(qF(ppoints(n)), sort(x))
qqline(y=sort(x), distribution=qF) # fine

## 2) Q-Q plot in log10-x space
plot(qF(ppoints(n)), sort(x), log="x")
qqline(y=sort(x), distribution=qF, untf=TRUE) # with untf=TRUE, fine

## 3) Q-Q plot in log10-y space
plot(qF(ppoints(n)), sort(x), log="y")
qqline(y=sort(x), distribution=qF, untf=TRUE) # with untf=TRUE, fine
```

Now the `?abline` addresses `untf`. According to that, the following should also work (in my opinion):

```
## 4) Q-Q plot in log10-log10 space
plot(qF(ppoints(n)), sort(x), log="xy")
qqline(y=sort(x), distribution=qF, untf=TRUE) # ... but this is wrong
qqline(y=sort(x), distribution=qF, col="red") # ... (still) wrong
qqline(y=sort(log10(x)), distribution=function(p) log10(qF(p)), col="blue") # seems to be correct (but draws a line, not the curve resulting from transforming the Q-Q line in 'non-log-log' space)
```

My questions are: 1) Why does `untf=TRUE` not give the right answer for `log="xy"` although it did for `log="x"` and `log="y"`? 2) On a more general basis, what's the 'right' Q-Q line in log-log-space (anyways)?

Please note that I have posted a similar question to [R-help](https://www.stat.math.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2013-June/356127.html), but have not received an answer.

**UPDATE**

I did more experiments, reproducing (by foot) the strange curve that `qqline()` in log-log space produces. I also figure that `log10()` instead of `log()` might be the reason for an incorrect line. So the blue line indeed seems to be the correct one *if* one wants to have a *line* in log-log space. What is not clear to me is why the points of the standard Q-Q line displayed in log-log scale do not give the right curve, although the points of the Q-Q plot are constructed this way, too.

```
th <- 0.5
n <- 1e2 # note the difference for n=1e2 vs n=1e4!
set.seed(271)
x <- rgamma(n, shape=th)
qF <- function(p) qgamma(p, shape=th)

## Q-Q plot
qq.x <- qF(ppoints(n))
qq.y <- sort(x)
plot(qq.x, qq.y, log="xy", main=substitute("Q-Q plot with sample size n="*n., list(n.=n)),
     xlab="Theoretical quantiles", ylab="Sample quantiles")
abline(v=quantile(qq.x, probs=0.25), col="gray50") # vertical line through 25%-quantile
abline(v=quantile(qq.x, probs=0.75), col="gray50") # vertical line through 75%-quantile
qqline(y=qq.y, distribution=qF, untf=TRUE) # ... this is wrong (*)
qqline(y=qq.y, distribution=qF, col="red") # ... still wrong
## => doesn't pass first and third quartile, but closer to 'right' line (blue) for large n
qqline(y=sort(log10(x)), distribution=function(p) log10(qF(p)), col="blue")
## => seems to be correct (but draws a line, not the curve resulting from transforming
##    the Q-Q line in 'non-log-log' space)

## by foot (as will be seen, this reproduces (*))
probs <- c(0.25, 0.75)
q.x <- qF(probs)
q.y <- quantile(x, probs=probs, names=FALSE)
slope <- diff(q.y)/diff(q.x)
int <- q.y[1L] - slope * q.x[1L]
f <- function(x) slope * x + int # line in *normal* space
qq.y. <- f(qq.x) # points of the Q-Q line evaluated in normal space
lines(qq.x, qq.y., col="darkgreen")
## => reproduces qqline(.., untf=TRUE), see (*) above, that is,
##    standard Q-Q line added to a plot in log-log scale = wrong (although points
##    of the Q-Q plot are constructed this way!)

## legend
legend("topleft", lty=rep(1,5), col=c("darkgreen", "black", "red", "blue", "gray50"),
       legend=c("Standard Q-Q line with 'untf=TRUE'",
                "Standard Q-Q line plotted in log-log scale",
                "Standard Q-Q line",
                "Q-Q line of log10(x) vs log10-quantiles", "1st and 3rd quartiles"))
```

Comment: @CarlWitthoft `qqline` will pass its `...` arguments to `abline` so that's ok.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft: This is why I wrote "`abline` addresses `untf`".

Comment: @HongOoi  I stand corrected.  Who'd have thought? :-)  Ok, so Marius, try running `abline` directly inside your different axis sets (log='xy', etc) to see if the problem is purely `abline` or only happens when calling it from `qqline` .

Comment: What do you mean by "'inside' your different axis sets"? All the functions which are called are fairly small, I already took a look at the source but `abline()` essentially calls `C_abline()` to which `untf` is passed...

Comment: `qqline` uses `abline`, and `abline` needs an intercept and slope, looking into how does it calculated the intercept and the slope should solve your problem. I think it has nothing to do with `C_abline`

Comment: I'm sorry, but that does not help at all. I know well how a line is computed... :-)